# Rails 5: send local variable to mailer view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looping through a collection like so:

```
<% @event_emails.each do |email| %>
  <%= render file: "event_emails_mailer/#{email.code.downcase}", locals: { @body: "body" } %>
<% end %>
```

The render is finding the correct view, but the `@body` variable isn't being passed along.

I've tried a number of different syntaxes for passing @body as a local variable. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Do you get any error? Also, you should pass `locals: { body: "body" }` and print body variable in your partial to verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that passing local parameters to mailer views doesn't work as easily as passing from regular controller views.

The solution that worked was to set the local variable within the loop and remove the locals parameter like so:

```
<% @event_emails.each do |email| %>
  <% @body = email.body %>
  <%= render file: "event_emails_mailer/#{email.code.downcase}" %>
<% end %>
```